# Find number x equal to sum of 1 number from n sets

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having the following problem:

I have n sorted collections of integers (2<n<10).
I have a number x.
I wanna know if there is a sum (there can be multiple), in which each set needs to contribute exactly 1 number, which is equal to x

**Example 1:**
Collection 1: {1, 2, 3, **5**, 7, 8}
Collection 2: {2, **4**, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11 23}
x: 9
For this example, a possible sum is 5+4. Another possibility is 1+8.

**Example2:**
Collection 1: {1, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9}
Collection 2: {2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}
x: 8
In this example, there is no possible sum. The number 8 is in both collections but since all collections need to contribute in the summation, this doesn't matter.

I don't wanna brute force this so i'm thinking recursion could make this process a bit faster but i don't really know where to begin.
I'm looking for some kind of train of thought although pseudo code or working code (java) would be appreciated :)

Comment: Recursion is not about optimizing performance. It's about logical simplification.

Comment: Iterating through the first collection, determine if the other collections can provide the remainder.  The answer (at each subsequent collection) can be memoized so the next time that value needs to be checked the answer will already be known.

Comment: What kind of results do you want? A Boolean whether there is such a sum or the number of all possible combinations or a list of all possible combinations

Comment: a boolean is just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static boolean existSum(List<Collection<Integer>> collections, int x) {
    int size = collections.size();
    return new Object() {
        boolean find(int index, int sum) {
            if (index >= size)
                return sum == x;
            for (int i : collections.get(index)) {
                int newSum = sum + i;
                if (newSum > x)
                    break;
                if (find(index + 1, newSum))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }.find(0, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(existSum(List.of(
        List.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8),
        List.of(2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 23)), 9));
    System.out.println(existSum(List.of(
        List.of(1, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9),
        List.of(2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9)), 8));
}
```

output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: This code gives the wrong answer when the number of collections passed in is greater than two.